# how to get text of few child nodes as single string

Tags: html, xpath

how can I get or compare text that is split into few nodes? For example:

```
<label>
  <span class="first">first part</span>
  <span class="second">second part</span>
  <span class="third">third part</span>
</label>
```

How to get string "first partsecond partthird part" and use it for comparison with text() function?

And more complicated example:

```
<label>
  <span class="first">first part</span>
  <span class="second">second part</span>
 something between
  <span class="third">third part</span>
</label>
```

How to get string "first partsecond partsomething betweenthird part" and use it for comparison with text() function?

Obviously, wouldbe nice to strip the result from unnecessary spaces with normalize-space(), but the key is how to concatenate those children's texts.

Comment: Do you want a CLI solution under Linux ? If not, add your programming language !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following xpath:

```
//label/descendant::*/text() | //label/text()[normalize-space()]
```

You may see some white spaces around 'something between' which you can trim using the programming language whatever you use.

Comment: Vimal, perhaps I'm completely dumb, but those XPath expressions return sets of nodes? While I need a string instead. Tell me, is it possible? I'm asking because I need to select some input fields using its labels, those labels contains a lot of spans and I need concatenate those little parts into strings. I can do it using some programming language, but would awesome to do it in XPath. Is it possible? Just tell me, how to check using XPath only if text content of first and second example is "first partsecond partthird part" and "first partsecond partsomething betweenthird part" respectively?

Comment: I understand your point. But XPath returns the list of nodes matching if more than one available. You can join all the value of the nodes as per your preference.

Comment: So I need to combine those nodes in programing language that I use? I cannot concatenate nodes string using only XPath?

Comment: Yes you are correct. XPATH doesn't have any concatenation.